# Use URLs with special characters in nginx maps

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup a redirect system with nginx (somthing like [aka.ms](https://aka.ms), [aka.ms/terminal-docs](https://aka.ms/terminal-docs) = documentation of Windows Terminal). I created a file with a map that look like this:

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri{
        [...]
        /youtube        https://www.youtube.com/channel/[...];
        [...]
}
```

Then i tried to add a `/odysee` link in the following way:

```
/odysee https://odysee.com/$/invite/@[...]:4;
```

But when reloading nginx it fail

```
# systemctl reload nginx
Job for nginx.service failed.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I am thinking it fails because of the `$` in Odysee's URL but i can't find a way to tell nginx to ignore the character

Comment: The dollar literal is being interpreted as a variable name. There is a creative solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57466554/how-do-i-escape-in-nginx-variables) that might help you.

Comment: BTW, `nginx -t` is a good way to check what exactly are the errors.

Comment: Seriously, again, run `nginx -t` and post the output.